# How many problems does my shed's 240V receptacle have?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, receptacle

I have a detached shed that was wired by somebody who evidently thought codes were just a friendly suggestion. I'm slowly trying to correct the electrical sins as I find them.

In this shed is the following 240V receptacle:

[image: 240V receptacle]

The receptacle is wired as follows:

[image: 240V receptacle wiring]

The wire that feeds it is 10/2, with this stamped on the side:

> E30445 (UL) AWG 10-2 WITH AWG 10 GROUND TYPE UF 600V SUNLIGHT RESISTANT

And that's fed from the following double-pole breaker:

[image: 60A double-pole breaker]

This receptacle is the only thing on the circuit. Total wire length is roughly 80-100 feet one-way.

As I understand it, I have the following problems:

1. It looks like the receptacle is a 10-30R, which as I understand is frowned upon today because it doesn't provide a ground prong.
2. It doesn't seem okay to use the ground wire in a 10/2 cable as the neutral.
3. The breaker seems way oversized for this application, unless I'm misunderstanding how current works with double-pole breakers. It's not clear to me if "internal common trip" changes anything.
4. Other problem(s) I'm not aware of?

I'm looking for the most reasonable way to make this safe and code-compliant, bearing in mind that I don't even have a use for this receptacle right now. I know I always have the option of removing the receptacle from the wall, pulling the breaker out of the panel, and capping the wire at both ends. I'm curious what it would take to fix it right, however.

**Bonus question:** Does anybody have any idea what purpose a 240V receptacle in a shed could serve? My guess is the previous owner was using some kind of heater or heavy-duty tool -- what could it have been?

Comment: First off, #10 wire is only good for 30 amps.  The breaker is way oversized.

Comment: I've seen older homes wire up 240V outlets like this in sheds/garages when installing a clothes dryer and the house was designed before indoor laundry facilities were common.  Installing it in a shed can be a lot easier since you don't have to modify your house, especially when it comes to the exhaust vent (common to vent out a nearby window with a sheet of wood where the glass would normally be).

Comment: Bonus comment: 240V could be used to run a large tool, like a lathe or welder.  Perhaps the shed was used as a workshop in the past ?

Comment: I know this is old, but one thing I haven't seen addressed. How does the wire in this pic get to this outlet? Is there a panel in the shed and this runs to the panel? Is this run through conduit to the main panel in the house? Is this cable direct buried?

Comment: @FreeMan This runs straight to the main house panel; no subpanels are involved. Accessible portions of the cable are in plastic conduit, but once it goes below grade I have no idea if it's direct-buried or not.

Comment: heh... just realized this is an 18 month old question. Thanks for responding anyway! Hope you've got the whole shed sorted by now.

Answer (score 12):

### The problematic receptacle

Use of a NEMA 10 family receptacle is illegal today.  **It was always illegal with that cable type, which is a "/2 + ground" type**, for reasons I go into in comments on George Anderson's answer.  Use of SE cable was legal, but only to help dealers use up their remaining stocks.  So the NEMA 10 must go; you don't have the right cable for it, and so it's not grandfathered.

### Install a universal junction box.

I would fit a 4-11/16" square steel box there, set about 4" lower on the wall. (to give you the legally required wire length.  Note that in your installation, wire length is precious; don't CUT wires off the old recep, unscrew them).

For wire length, you need 6-1/4" past the cable clamp; plus 3" beyond the surface of the wall.

Then, on the 4-11/16" square box, add a 1-gang *mud ring* (not a dome).  That will you give you a 1-gang space for any recep, and also LOTS OF ROOM behind the box for GFCI, AFCI, bulky receps etc.  You also have space to change to a 2-gang mud ring, to allow GFCI + second recep.  The box also has room for extending wiring to other points of use e.g. lights.

### Fit the receps you want

Once that universal box is in, fit whatever receps you want:

- For 240V, a NEMA 6-30.  OR
- For 120V @ 30A, a NEMA TT30, or L5-30
- For 120V @ 20A, the common 5-20 or dual 5-15.

You must choose 120V or 240V.  You can't have both unless you add a subpanel and a proper 120-240--240/480V supply transformer, which will give you both, totaling 7,200W.  You can also go "two transformers" which will give you 14,400W or up to 18,000W.  The cost of these will rise exponentially with increasing power because of size and scarcity of the transformers.

### Now change the breaker (mandatory)

According to Code, the breaker size must match the receptacle size.  (with one exception: if the circuit has *two or more* 15A sockets, a 20A breaker is allowed.)

I recommend a 2-pole, 20A or 30A breaker, because it'll fill the hole completely.  A 1-pole breaker is $5 and a 2-pole is $10.  A blanking plate is $3 + *$50 of your time* just running around trying to find somebody who has the darn thing in stock (won't be a big-box store).   So I use breakers to fill empty holes.

Also do not under any circumstances buy a 30A, 1-pole breaker.  They are completely useless for any application except certain small travel trailers (which take a TT30).  If you need one, buy a 30A/2-pole instead, which  have many applications.  *You'll thank me later*.

The 60A breaker is perfectly usable and about $10 to buy a new one. They're good for subpanels or bigger EVSE's. Do with it what you will.

Comment: Looks like there's a loop of excess cable inside the wall below the receptacle, so the wire length isn't quite as precious as it could be. I'm leaning toward the 6-30 receptacle option, and swapping in the correct breaker ASAP.

Comment: @smitelli That's legit.  Just keep in mind you'd only be able to power 240V compressors, welders etc.  There's no such thing as a 6-30 to 120V outlet adapter cable... at least *there shouldn't* be; though some crooked sellers on eBay/Amazon Marketplace will cheerfully make you a dangerous thing like that.  Also using a cheapie $100 stepdown transformer has a 50/50 chance of being dangerous. I was referring to an isolating 120-240--240/480V service transformer.

Comment: Would it be reasonable for OP to add a new earth stake out at the shed?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe used for a welder? Kiln?   The worst thing right now is the breaker "protecting" the circuit. It's double what it should be.  10ga wire in cable is rated at 30 amps!  Not 60!!!

The wiring on your outlet is OK, just dated.   It's fine for a 240v only appliance: 2 hots and a ground.   Not code legal anymore,  but commonly done for clothes dryers in the past.

What are your goals for power in the shed?  Just a simple outlet?  Multiple outlets? 240v outlet? A sub-panel? The problem with a sub-panel is you don't have a 4 wire feed to the building.   I suppose you could do a 120v only sub-panel...not sure.  One of the big-three here could weigh in on that.

Comment: Did a quick lookup on 120v sub-panel.  Looks like you just jumper the 2 hots, connect the white wire to the neutral bussbar (NOT BONDED to ground) and connect the ground wire to a separate buss bar bonded to the sub-panel.  If you go the sub-panel route, you'll need to install ground rods as well. In the main panel feeding this you'd have to swap out the double pole breaker with a 30 amp single pole breaker and connect the white wire to the neutral.   ...Again, your electrical needs in the shed will determine what choices you make.

Comment: Harper, I must disagree. the 1996 code changed this from 3-wire to 4-wire for dryers. There are lots of posts showing how to change from 3-prong to 4-prong, so it must have been legal at some point.

Comment: Maybe note that the outlet should be placed into an electrical box?

Comment: @user3757614 That type of surface mount receptacle is supposed to be its own box.  We might complain about the unprotected NM entering the bottom.  There is a knock out in the back of the receptacle that is supposed to be used when wall mounting like this, but its not a big deal the way it is.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson In terms of goals, my immediate goal is to not have a fire. Beyond that, I don't know what I'd use this outlet (or even most of the shed) for. It's a new place to me, and I feel like I'll have a better sense once I've lived here a while. It's nice to know what my options are for the future, though.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  You're misunderstanding what I'm saying.  Back when 3-wire was legal, you were supposed to use insulated neutrals, *except* an exception was cut to allow use of (then, common) #10 SE cable.  SE cable is for service drops, the conductors are H-H-N.  Idiots decided that since SE's neutral is uninsulated, therefore /2+gnd cable must be alright too.  Code *never* said that.  The bare-neutral exception was only ever valid for SE, USE and SE-R cable. (all SE cable). And even that was just to let the supply chain use up their stock of #10 SE, which had no use after that.

Comment: In other words, Code intentionally put you in a bind: 3-wire connections were legal, but only if you used obsolete cable that was now unobtanium.  The idiots decided "since that cable type no longer exists in market, that implies it must be legal to substitute other cable types".  Code never implied that.  Code's goal was to force everyone to 4-wire connections as soon as the supply of SE was exhausted.  #10 SE died because of Code changes requiring >40A service drops and grounds on subpanel runs.

Comment: Harper, thanks for the response. You know a lot more about the code than I do...you have very detailed knowledge. But from a practical approach, it might not make a lot of difference if the appliance was 240v with no need for a neutral.   Still, the exact details of NEC on specific wiring is not my strong suit.   Again, thanks for the clarification/contribution.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Oh, what I'm saying is arcane as heck.  I doubt 10% of electrical inspectors even know it.  You're absolutely correct, retasking this for a 240V+ground+no neutral is fine.  the only thing unacceptable here is the NEMA 10 socket.  (well and the breaker lol).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  LOL, yeah I get that.   But it just depends upon what the OP wants.   Retasking this run to a 120v only sub-panel is easy as described above.   The OPs situation isn't dire, just turn off the 60 amp breaker and don't use the circuit until it's up to spec.

Comment: That wiring isn't fine - it's not in conduit and runs **right between the panelling and the face of the stud!**.  One little nail tacked through the wall, especially with that 60A 2-pole behind it, could make one hell of a pop.

Comment: @J I didn't say it was "fine", I said it was "ok" which is less than "fine" IMHO.   You are of course right in that the wire should have come into the back of the surface mounted receptacle, but other than that...  I've seen MUCH WORSE.

Answer (score 3):

You had a pretty accurate knowledge of what was wrong with the outlet and George summed it up nicely. 
One thought to make it safe, and usable, would be to remove the outlet and add a regular metal box, cover and 20 Amp GFCI outlet. At the panel, add a 20 Amp breaker right below the existing 60 as a slot's already available. Remove the black wire from the 60 amp breaker and add install it in the 20 Amp breaker. Remove the white wire from the 60 amp breaker and install it on the neutral buss bar. Check that the ground wire from that circuit is actually connected to the ground buss bar and not the neutral bar. If it is connected to the neutral, remove it and install it on the ground bar.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like the receptacle is a 10-30R, which as I understand is frowned upon today because it doesn't provide a ground prong.

Indeed, the socket is nominally two hots and a Neutral.

IIRC it used to be allowed to use the neutral as a ground in certain circumstances, but it was never allowed to use a ground as a neutral. So the nema 10 socket has to go. Furthermore tha 60A breaker also has to go.

If you want to keep the existing wiring then I think you have a few options.

1. Reduce the breaker to 30A and convert it to a 240V only 30A circuit (with a 6-30 socket)
2. Reduce the breaker to 20A and convert it to a 240V only 20A circuit (with a 6-20 socket)
3. Reduce the breaker to 20A, turn the white wire into a neutral and convert it to a 120V only circuit.

Personally for now i'd just disconnect it, if/when you have a need for more power in your garage then you can determine whether the wire you have in place is useful for the load you plan to connect and buy the relavent breaker and socket at that time.

Answer (score -2):

#1: Replace that 60A breaker with something smaller, immediately.
#2: OP never said whether ground wire in cable was tied to neutral, or to ground back at the source.  I will assume ground.
#3: A 240V welder plug, suitably installed, should be A-OK.  You can plug a welder into it, or a 240V space heater.  Nothing that expects to run 120V anything by also referring to neutral, such as most appliances these days.

Comment: 1) This doesn't add anything to answers that have already been here for more than a year. 2) OP indicated that the ground was being used as a neutral, so it's _NOT_ safe to assume it's a ground. Plus that's how NEMA 10 outlets work - they _don't_ have a ground. 3) It's not "A-OK" to install anything other than a dryer to a NEMA 10 outlet and that's _only_ if it's properly installed, which other answers have indicated that this one isn't.

Comment: Yeah -- if you want to plug a 240V-only thing into it, you need to make sure that the former neutral can be used as a ground, then swap the receptacle to NEMA 6